# Can not type right text to QtLineEdit

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new in Qt. I want to type "Tôi đang ăn cơm" string to QtLineEdit, but it shown like this:

[image]

What should I do?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you mean that when you *type* with your keyboard, it appears like that? What system are you on, with which Qt and python versions?

Comment: Yes, I type from my keyboard, and it appears like that. My system is Windows 10, Qt 4.8.6 version, and Python 3.7

Comment: You are using a *very* old and unsupported version of Qt (it's support ended 5 years ago). You really should update to the latest Qt5. Also, be more careful about the tags you use.